# Array[] em banco de dados, como criar e manipular?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, array, arraylist

Eu possuo um *array* de inteiros, um `int[]`.

É possível salvá-lo diretamente no banco de dados sem precisar Serializar? Como por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE teste(
    numeros integer[]
);
```

E depois usar `SELECT numeros FROM teste`? Pesquisei e não achei muita informação sobre isso principalmente em Java, a maioria é tudo em PHP.

É recomendado fazer isso? Ou é melhor serializar?

Comment: Você pode usar o tipo JSON e salvar nesse formato, salvar como string no formato que quiser, por exemplo, CSV, ou criar uma tabela números e adicionar uma linha pra cada número referenciado a tabela original

Comment: Acho que salvar me JSON seria valido também, embora eu não estivesse afim de usar JSON eu acho que isso também é valido, acho que vou seguir a dica do Maniero e vou serializar mesmo.

Comment: QUe caminho você foi?

Comment: Eu optei por salvar em `Text` no banco de dados, usei `StringJoiner` pra formatar no java e depois transformei em `String` pra salvar no banco de dados. Na hora de obter os dados de volta do banco eu uso a função `split`, funciona tudo perfeitamente sem erros e esta bem otimizado.

Answer (score 4):

Só no PostgreSQL (entre os mais conhecidos) pode fazer isso e mesmo assim passará por alguma adaptação antes de gravar ou recuperar informação. Em qualquer outro banco de dados terá que criar um mecanismo próprio de manipulação de gravação e recuperação de dados no banco de dados.

O mais comum é fazer isso via `VARCHAR` onde você definirá um formato onde terá os dados (JSON é só um exemplo), podendo usar um separador, um tamanho padrão ou outra forma, que no fundo é uma forma de serializar, seja por texto ou binário. Se for fazer binário é melhor usar um `BLOB`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: então o objeto to tipo `Array` do `java.sql` serve apenas para o PostgreSQL? Tava dando uma olhada na documentação do Java e encontrei isso, porém ao olhar na documentação do MySQL não achei nada falando sobre. (por isso resolvi criar o tópico)

Comment: Para criar o Array `connection.createArrayOf(typeName, elements)` e para resgatar o Array `resultSet.getArray(columnLabel)`

Comment: Não sei o que é `java.sql` e sua pergunta não o cita.

Comment: `java.sql` é a package da classe `Array`